# Metric choice in the tangent space of a Riemannian manifold obtained through the Log map

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, tangent-spaces

After using the Log map, as defined in this paper [Riemannian approaches in Brain-Computer Interfaces: a
review](https://inria.hal.science/hal-01394253/document) (Section III. A page 2&3), to project points from the manifold onto the tangent space  $T_P(M)$, do we use the metric defined by the ambient Euclidean space or the Riemannian metric to measure distances and norms of the vectors in the tangent space?

On one hand, I feel that the Riemannian metric should be used since it is what defines angles, distances, and norms on the tangent space. However, on the other hand, the tangent space $T_P(M)$ obtained through the Log map seems to be a Euclidean space, which can be viewed as a local linearization of the manifold around the point P (which I think can be viewed as a chart)?

I think this might be related to pullback, induced metrics, and these posts [What is the difference between a chart and a tangent space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3035157/what-is-the-difference-between-a-chart-and-a-tangent-space) and [Tangent Space and Charts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993676/tangent-space-and-charts), but I do not have a background in this field at all, so if someone could point me in the right direction and help clear up terminology and confusion that would be great! If the answer is the Euclidean metric, could someone explain why after the log map we no longer use the Riemannian metric to compare vectors in the tangent space. Alternatively, if the answer is the Riemannian metric, could someone explain why the projection onto the tangent space using the log map is not a local linearization and the geometry/curvature induced by the metric is not already accounted for by the log map?

**Edit: My best guess answer based on intuition**

If you project a set of points via the log map onto the tangent space centered at their mean, you have created a local linearization of the manifold centered around the mean. If you are not interested in the geodesic distance between these points but are just interested in clustering or finding linear distances between points then I believe using the metric defined by the ambient Euclidean space should suffice. Since the log map approximates the manifolds geometry close points on the manifold will be close in the tangent space and far points will be far (given your approximation is accurate).

However, since I believe the using the Riemannian metric on the tangent space allows us to measure how far movement in the tangent space corresponds with movement on the manifold, if you are interested in approximating the geodesic distance between projected points then you should use the Riemannian metric. Additionally, I believe if you are interested in comparing projected points on the tangent space to any other points on the tangent space (not necessarily from the set you projected) then you should use the Riemannian metric as well since this will again give you an estimate as to how far on the manifold these points actually are.

Comment: What do you mean by "the" Euclidean metric on a vector space? There are many inner products to choose from. The Riemannian metric provides one.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Sorry, I was referring to the standard euclidean inner product/dot product

Comment: There is no such a thing as the "standard" dot product unless you have a preferred set of coordinates on your vector space. In the setting of manifolds, you do not have a preferred basis in any tangent space.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I changed the link to a freely available pdf. Since there is no preferred set of coordinate bases, how do you define the distance between two vectors on the tangent space after you have projected one of the points on the tangent space using the log map?

Comment: The *definition* of a Riemannian metric is the specification of a dot product on each tangent space. The definition of the length of a tangent vector or angle between two tangent vector uses *only* the dot product.

Comment: I think I see the source of your confusion: In the paper they work with a manifold that is an open subset of a Euclidean space. Hence, on each tangent space you have two (potentially) different inner products (one given by the ambient Euclidean space and the other given by the chosen Riemannian metric). In order to figure out which inner product is used in a certain part of the paper requires you to read closely what they are actually doing. On general grounds, one cannot tell.

Comment: @Deane If I understand you correctly you are saying that the Riemannian metric is the dot product to use on the tangent space since that is the definition of it? That make sense/what I figured, but I am confused about the last part of my question then "why the projection onto the tangent space using the log map is not a local linearization and the geometry/curvature induced by the metric is not already accounted for by the log map"

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you, I think this makes sense! If I understand correctly, in this specific case, once we've employed the Log map to project vectors from the manifold onto the tangent space using the Riemannian metric, haven't we essentially incorporated the geometry of the manifold into this representation? If so would using the Riemannian metric or the metric defined by the ambient euclidean space better approximate the geodesic distance between these points on the manifold?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. At the same time, I found not make any assumptions about what the authors are actually doing; one never a priori knows if they do a natural thing (as you wrote in the comment) or something else.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Sorry, which part of the question was the Yes, absolutely to and which part is the natural thing? Thanks again for all the clarifications

Comment: Using the Riemannian metric is the natural thing.